# ASP.NET Self Hosting or IIS hosting

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net web api application should I use Self Hosting or should I host it on IIS. I am looking for better performance and security. Which one should I be using?

Comment: iis, or you need to implement a lot of security features on your own. DDOS

Comment: Is there a way where I can configure IIS from a config file which can be done for apache ? As I will be exporting the web application onto another machine. So that it would make life easier for a customer who is hosting it all by himself ?

Comment: yes google the `web.config` file. also take a look [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754617(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Really?  This a major architectural decision (at least I'd like to think so).  Given the amount of thought that has gone into the question I'd say flip a coin.  In a pinch, I would suggest `iis` since it will give you so much out of the box and your client will not have to install anything.  I a trivial case an `xcopy` deployment would work.

Answer (score -1):

I just show the answer from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1908235.aspx?Self+hosting+or+IIS+hosted+).

> What I've found (basically just pros for IIS hosted):
>
> - You lose all of the features of IIS (logging, application pool scaling,  >throttling/config of your site, etc.)...
> - You have to build every single feature that you want yourself HttpContext?
> - You lose that since ASP.NET provides that for you. So, I could see that making things like authentication much harder WebDeploy?
> - IIS has some nice specific features in 8 about handling requests and warming up the service (self-hosted does not)
> - IIS has the ability to run multiple concurrent sites with applications and virtual directories to advanced topics like load balancing and remote deployments.

And this

> Self-hosting is good when you're not on a server -- for example, you want a desktop app to be able to listen for API requests.

But I think you would be able to achive am faster performing and more stable server if it is worth your time. But you need to be carefull not to make basic security mistakes like public accessable configuration files or ddos.